# Pull to refresh text is placed above tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, z-index

I am trying to have my entire refreshControl placed behind the tableview.  I am able place the actual spinner by doing this:

```
  self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
  self.tableView.sendSubview(toBack: refreshControl)
```

The only issue is the text associated with the spinner is placed on top of the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl
```

Comment: This guy knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.
You just need to change `zPosition` of your refreshControl.

`refreshControl.layer.zPosition = -1`